# Inline SVG clipPath with % and px values?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am clipping a div with a clip path like this:

```
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 80px, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
clip-path: polygon(0 80px, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
```

In order to ensure compatibility with Firefox, I've created an inline SVG image to link to:

```
<svg width=" ? " height=" ? ">
  <defs>
  <clipPath id="clip-shape" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <polygon points="0 80px, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%" />
  </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>

-webkit-clip-path: url(#clip-shape);
clip-path: url(#clip-shape);
```

Which doesn't work because seems like it wants me to define polygon points without % or px:

```
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
  <clipPath id="clip-shape" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <polygon points="0 XXX (I want pixels here), 1 0, 1 1, 0 1" />
  </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

It works this way, however I am out of ideas on how to insert a px based value in it (80px in the first example).